# neo4j rest api cypher appears to return cartesian product of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've created a simple graph using the following data:

```
CREATE (england:Country {Name:"England",Id:1})
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Country) ASSERT c.ID IS UNIQUE

CREATE (john:King {Name:"John",Id:1})
CREATE (henry3:King {Name:"Henry III",Id:2})
CREATE (edward1:King {Name:"Edward I",Id:3})
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (k:King) ASSERT k.ID IS UNIQUE
MATCH (country:Country),(king:King) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND king.Id = 1 CREATE (country)<-[r:KING_OF]-(king)
MATCH (country:Country),(king:King) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND king.Id = 2 CREATE (country)<-[r:KING_OF]-(king)
MATCH (country:Country),(king:King) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND king.Id = 3 CREATE (country)<-[r:KING_OF]-(king)

CREATE (cornwall:County {Name:"Cornwall",Id:1})
CREATE (devon:County {Name:"Devon",Id:2})
CREATE (somerset:County {Name:"Somerset",Id:3})
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:County) ASSERT c.ID IS UNIQUE
MATCH (country:Country),(county:County) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND county.Id = 1 CREATE (country)<-[r:COUNTY_IN]-(county)
MATCH (country:Country),(county:County) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND county.Id = 2 CREATE (country)<-[r:COUNTY_IN]-(county)
MATCH (country:Country),(county:County) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND county.Id = 3 CREATE (country)<-[r:COUNTY_IN]-(county)

CREATE (bristol:City {Name:"Bristol",Id:1})
CREATE (london:City {Name:"London",Id:2})
CREATE (york:City {Name:"York",Id:3})
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City) ASSERT c.ID IS UNIQUE
MATCH (country:Country),(city:City) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND city.Id = 1 CREATE (country)<-[r:CITY_IN]-(city)
MATCH (country:Country),(city:City) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND city.Id = 2 CREATE (country)<-[r:CITY_IN]-(city)
MATCH (country:Country),(city:City) WHERE country.Id = 1 AND city.Id = 3 CREATE (country)<-[r:CITY_IN]-(city)
```

(Note that I use 'thiscomputer.mydomain.com' as an alias for 'localhost', which SO ridiculously bars me from using)...

If I go to http://thiscomputer.mydomain.com:7474/browser/ and execute the cypher

```
MATCH cities = (city:City)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), counties = (county:County)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), kings = (king:King)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1})  RETURN cities, counties, kings
```

...I get a nice graph centred around the country of England. No nodes are repeated.

If I fire up a REST client and execute the following:

URL: `http://thiscomputer.mydomain.com:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`
Verb: `POST`
Body:

```
{
  "statements" : [{
"statement": "MATCH cities = (city:City)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), counties = (county:County)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), kings = (king:King)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1})  RETURN cities, counties, kings",
"resultDataContents" : [ "graph" ]
}]
}
```

(Note that the cypher query is identical)

I end up with a set of results that are too large to paste in here.

Basically, I appear to get the cartesian product of the results. Since there are 3 kings, 3 counties and 3 cities, there are 27 results.

This is a fairly simple graph. In the domain in which I work, the graph I want would contain an aggregate root (in this example, England), and many associated nodes of different types. If the REST API returned the cartesian product, I could end up with many thousands of results.

So my question is this: why does the REST API return the cartesian product of all the returned nodes? Is my cypher incorrect, or am I using the REST API incorrectly?

It would be much simpler if I could get results like this (pseudo-JSON):

```
{
  Country:{
    Name: "England",
    Id: 1,
    Cities:[
      ...etc
    ],
    Counties:[
      ...etc
    ],
    Kings:[
      ...etc
    ]
  }
}
```

Or possibly even this:

```
{
  data:{
    nodes:[
      {
        Name:"England",
        Id: 1,
        uniqueIdInResults:1
      },
      ...etc
    ],
    relationships:[
      uniqueIdInResults1: 1,
      uniqueIdInResults2: 2,
      type: "KING_OF"
    ] 
  }
}
```

In short, I think denormalising the data in the results like this can quickly result in a response which is too large. Is there any way to structure the cypher or the call to the REST API to give results with less repetition?

Comment: Good point on improving the response format for the "graph" variant, as it doesn't need to separate into rows, but proably that's even a separate use-case. One with per row and one with a global graph returned.

Comment: What I'm interested in doing is loading an entire aggregate (in the DDD sense) with a single call. Whereas I assume this should be possible (a single index lookup to get the aggregate root, then pure graph traversal), I think the denormalisation makes the amount of data returned impractical.

Comment: I understand there are issues around how you represent polyhierarchical data using (for example) JSON, but my second suggestion (returning a list of nodes and a list of relationships) would be one approach, and much more efficient than a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3):

The query you are running in the browser is absolutely returning a Cartesian product as well - it just doesn't appear that way because the visual result will only show the nodes once.

Run the following in the browser. You'll see pretty quickly all the overlap you're getting.

```
MATCH cities = (city:City)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), 
      counties = (county:County)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1}), 
      kings = (king:King)-[]->(c:Country {Id:1})  
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(cities) | x.Name),
       EXTRACT(x IN NODES(counties) |x.Name), 
       EXTRACT(x IN NODES(kings) | x.Name)
```

As expected, I get a Cartesian product of 27 rows.

Comment: Thank you. It's not that I thought it was the REST API (as opposed to cypher) doing the denormalisation. I would just like to know if I can somehow coax the query into shaping the response data more efficiently.

Comment: I suppose I was referring to "...I get a nice graph centred around the country of England. No nodes are repeated." My point is that the visual result can be misleading in terms of redundant data / Cartesian products.

Comment: But I have little experience using the 'graph' result in REST so I'm not sure I'd be much help in editing your Cypher to get exactly what you want.